# android:layout_alignParentBottom not working in runtime

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout

I am using `android:layout_alignParentBottom` for the arrow down `ImageView` inside `RelativeLayout` for each item of `RecyleView`.
But it only work perfect in `Preview` mode, when I run app it doesn't work. I don't know why this happened.
I have explained more about my problem in the screenshot

In Preview
[image]
In runtime
[image]

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/item_layoutStart"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#E8F5E9"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_tvRepeatTime"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="10" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ff0"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/item_layoutStart"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/item_layoutStart"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_layoutStart">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_tvTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="aa aa aaaaaa aa aa aaaaaa aa aa aaaaaa " />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_tvResult"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/item_tvTitle"
                    android:text="aa aa aaaaaa aa aa aaaaaa aa aa aaaaaa" />
                <ImageView android:id="@+id/item_ivExpand"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/selector_arrow_down"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**UPDATE**
If I fix the height of my `RelativeLayout` by specific value, the `android:layout_alignParentBottom` **work**

```
 <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
 >
```

but in my case, I want `RelativeLayout` height equals `LinearLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/item_layoutStart"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/item_layoutStart"
               >
```

`android:layout_alignParentBottom` **not work**

Any help would be great aprreciated

Comment: replaced following line: android:layout_gravity="right"  in item_ivExpand with android:layout_gravity="right|bottom".

Comment: Change that `ImageView`'s parent `RelativeLayout`'s `layout_height` to `match_parent`.

Comment: @SagarTrehan thanks but it doesn't work. my problem still happened

Comment: @MikeM. thank but change `RelativeLayout's layout_height to match_parent` didn't change my layout. same issue as my post.
In my case I want the `relativelayout` have height equals to left layout (`LinearLayout`)

Comment: @MikeM. I'm really sorry, I post wrong color for `RelativeLayout`, the yellow view is the `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that that `RelativeLayout` was already matching its parent's height. Huh, that's odd.

Comment: @MikeM. yes `RelativeLayout` is match_parent in runtime, I have tried to clean code, run on different device but it still happend :(

Comment: @MikeM. I found a small clue and update it to my question. hope you can check it

Comment: Got it! Change the outer `RelativeLayout` to a `LinearLayout`. Then, on the inner `RelativeLayout`, remove `layout_alignTop` and `layout_alignBottom`, and set `layout_height` to `match_parent`.

Comment: @MikeM. thank you so much for your effort. now my preview layout look diffrent, but in runtime it look ok. I will use your solution now

Comment: Can you post the code you use when inflating the layout? A common error is to pass `null` for the parent view which causes all layout xml properties to be lost.

Comment: Yeah, I was testing on my device, and it definitely works there. The layout editor often doesn't lay things out exactly as the runtime framework does.

Comment: @Brucelet belive me. i'm sure I am `inflating the layout` correct ;)

Comment: No problem! Glad to help. I'll post an answer when I get a chance here in a little bit, with an explanation of why I believe that was happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this solution apparently messes with the way the layout looks in the editor, it solves the problem of the runtime layout.

First, change the outer `RelativeLayout` to a `LinearLayout`. Then, on the inner `RelativeLayout`, remove the `layout_alignTop` and `layout_alignBottom` attributes altogether, and set the `layout_height` to `match_parent`.

As you can see in the posted screenshots, that `ImageView` was being laid out as though its parent `RelativeLayout`'s height was wrapping its child `View`s, as per its `layout_height` setting. However, after the `RelativeLayout`'s child `View`s were laid out, its `layout_alignTop` and `layout_alignBottom` attributes were being applied, and it was resized to match the `LinearLayout`'s height, but that `ImageView` just stayed where it was.

By using a `LinearLayout` for the outer `ViewGroup`, and setting the inner `RelativeLayout`'s height to `match_parent`, the `RelativeLayout` had a definite height applied before it laid out its child `View`s, and the `ImageView`'s `layout_alignParentRight` and `layout_alignParentBottom` attributes landed it in the right spot.